# postgres error: mergejoin input data is out of order

Tags: sql, postgresql, semantic-versioning

I have two tables in my postgres database, relations and versioninfo:

```
postgres=# \d+ relations
                                                                 Table "public.relations"
                Column                |            Type             | Collation | Nullable | Default | Storage  | Compression | Stats target | Description 
--------------------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+---------+----------+-------------+--------------+-------------
 system_name                          | character varying           |           |          |         | extended |             |              | 
 from_package_name                    | character varying           |           |          |         | extended |             |              | 
 from_version                         | semver                      |           |          |         | plain    |             |              | 
 to_package_name                      | character varying           |           |          |         | extended |             |              | 
 actual_requirement                   | character varying           |           |          |         | extended |             |              | 
 to_version                           | semver                      |           |          |         | plain    |             |              | 
 to_package_highest_available_release | character varying           |           |          |         | extended |             |              | 
 interval_start                       | timestamp without time zone |           |          |         | plain    |             |              | 
 interval_end                         | timestamp without time zone |           |          |         | plain    |             |              | 
 is_out_of_date                       | boolean                     |           |          |         | plain    |             |              | 
 is_regular                           | boolean                     |           |          |         | plain    |             |              | 
 warnings                             | character varying           |           |          |         | extended |             |              | 
Access method: heap
```

```
postgres=# \d+ versioninfo
                                                    Table "public.versioninfo"
    Column    |            Type             | Collation | Nullable | Default | Storage  | Compression | Stats target | Description 
--------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+---------+----------+-------------+--------------+-------------
 system_name  | character varying           |           |          |         | extended |             |              | 
 package_name | character varying           |           |          |         | extended |             |              | 
 version_name | semver                      |           |          |         | plain    |             |              | 
 release_date | timestamp without time zone |           |          |         | plain    |             |              | 
Access method: heap
```

And I am joining them on some criteria:

```
CREATE TABLE exclude_records AS
SELECT R2.system_name, R2.from_package_name, R2.from_version, R2.to_package_name, COUNT(*) AS count_no
FROM relations R2
INNER JOIN versioninfo V3
ON R2.from_package_name = V3.package_name AND R2.from_version = V3.version_name AND R2.system_name = V3.system_name
INNER JOIN versioninfo V4
ON R2.to_package_name = V4.package_name AND R2.to_version = V4.version_name AND R2.system_name = V4.system_name
GROUP BY R2.system_name, R2.from_package_name, R2.from_version, R2.to_package_name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

But this query returns error:

```
ERROR:  mergejoin input data is out of order 

SQL state: XX000
```

Cannot figure out what the problem is. My understanding is that for joining the tables using inner join, postgres is using `mergejoin` (because the ON condition contains equal operators and those two table are very large). And that may be the reason for this error?

Comment: Just curious:  Do you get the error if you cast the `from_version`, `to_version`, and `version_name` to `text` in your query?  e.g. `. . . AND R2.from_version::text = v3.version_name::text. . .` and again at `R2.to_version::text = V4.version_name::text`?  I ask because there may be a bug or missing implementation in the semver extension that causes this.

Comment: Weirdly enough, after converting them to `VARCHAR` it is working properly. Thanks for the suggestion. But still not sure why using `SEMVER` was causing the error.

Comment: I suggest that you please take this up with the developers of the semver extension.  Your problem report here is very detailed, so if the project is under active development, then the developer(s) should be able to pinpoint the root cause fairly quickly.

Comment: It could be index corruption. Does a `REINDEX` of the involved tables fix the problem?